# any sum of sets open\nullset is a set of the same form

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm curious how can one prove that any sum of sets $G\setminus N$, where $G$ is open and the Lebesgue measure of $N$ is 0, is a set of the same form.

it is easy for countable sums, but in general?

-------------------------- Edited:

Yes, I mean $A\cup B$ (this is called union), not the sum $A+B$, sorry.

In general: we have an indexed family $\{A_i: i\in I\}$ (the set $I$ of indices may be uncountable) of subsets of the real line, each $A_i$ is of the form $G_i\setminus N_i$, where $G_i$ is open und $N_i$ is a nullset, the problem is how to prove that the union of all $A_i$'s is of the form $G\setminus N$, where $G$ open und $N$ nullset.

Comment: Hint: The sum (union) will contain $G$ and its difference from an open set will be contained in $N$

Comment: What do you mean in general? At most countable sums are allowed, right (we're doing measure theory / $\sigma$-algebras, I suppose)?

Comment: I edited the topic to explain all things mentioned above

Comment: There is a countable base for the open sets, and every null set is contains in a $G_\delta$ null set.